# Android Multiple Implementations

Tags: java, android, implementation

I am trying to something like this:

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements 
    SurfaceHolder.Callback && SensorEventListener {
```

I have also tried:

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements 
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, SensorEventListener {
```

Where I have both surface events and sensor events in one java class, but I cannot get it to work.  What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements 
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, SensorEventListener {
```

Comment: I tried that, but couldn't get it to work.  I am compiling with Java 1.6, but I cannot get the @Override to be accepted.  Don't I still need to override all the original functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot get the override to be accepted"? Do you get a compile error? I'd suggest you double-check if you really are compiling with Java 1.6 and not Java 1.5 (maybe you have Java 1.6 set globally but Java 1.5 in project-specific settings?) as I just pasted the above code and get no errors when I implement all the required methods (with @Override).

Comment: Okay, I have the SurfaceHolder.Callback, SensorEventListener in my class declaration thing.  I was unable to get the project to build with @ Override before any of the event functions, like onSensorChanged(), so I removed the @ Override, and it builds, but the methods are never triggered.  Do you have any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Not without seeing more of your code. You should open a new question with more code shown there (editing this question is probably not the best idea since this one's about interface inheritance syntax). And if you had to remove @Override for it to compile then you definitely must have compliance set to 1.5 somewhere.